# ImportError: No module named geopandas

Tags: python

I just ran this code and got this error, I'm not sure why:

```
%matplotlib inline
​
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import pysal as ps
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pet
```

> ImportError: No module named geopandas

Comment: Is geopandas installed? Try pip install geopandas (you will also need geos_c library installed on your OS for this)

Comment: I am having the same issue. pip failed with fiona. So tried conda and then conda-forge. Still ending up with: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopandas'

Comment: Same here. geopandas *is* installed in my Anaconda environment. it shows up in the list in the Anaconda Navigator. Also, in the Anaconda prompt, with the environment activated, when giving the command *conda list*, it turns up in the list.
Still, in Spyder but also when just starting Python from the command prompt, *import geopandas* results in that error.
I've tried the ipython solution (see other answer) but ipython is already included in the envuironment.

Answer (score 18):

Check if geopandas is installed

```
>>> import sys
>>> 'geopandas' in sys.modules
False                            => Not Installed
>>>
```

To install the released version, you can use pip:

```
pip install geopandas
```

or you can install the conda package from the conda-forge channel:

```
conda install -c conda-forge geopandas
```

You may install the latest development version by cloning the GitHub repository and using the setup script:

```
git clone https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas.git
cd geopandas
pip install .
```

It is also possible to install the latest development version directly from the GitHub repository with:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/geopandas/geopandas.git
```

Linux?

```
sudo apt-get install python-geopandas
```

Comment: Any idea why after installing pip3 install geopandas under the conda virtual env returns false when invoking ''geopandas' in sys.modules'? 

If I do 'conda install -c conda-forge geopandas' it returns true...

Comment: I tried both 'conda install -c conda-forge geopandas'  and 'Conda install geopandas' under virtual env and still get False and no module found error, any idea?

Comment: Your answer does not address the question. The OP has already tried installing it successfully and still not succeeding in getting it to work

Answer (score 8):

You might encounter this problem even if `geopandas` **is** correctly installed in your active environment. Your problem might be related to `ipython` not being installed in the environment you installed `geopandas` in. In this case `ipython` from outside of the environment is used and will find no module named `geopandas` resulting in a `ImportError`.

Assuming a Linux OS:

- You can check which `ipython` is used with `where ipython`.
- You can install `ìpython` in your active environment by executing `conda install ipython`.

Answer (score 3):

If using Jupyter notebook with conda use:

```
conda install -c conda-forge geopandas
```

Comment: That worked for me when I entered `conda install -c conda-forge geopandas` from within a notebook, but it didn't work when I tried from within bash.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any trouble installing GeoPandas, just follow the below steps:

⦁   Go to Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages. ([https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/))

⦁   Download the following binaries in a specifi folder in your laptop/PC:

GDAL,

Pyproj,

Fiona,

Shapely &

Geopandas

matching the version of Python, and whether the 32-bit or 64-bit OS is installed on your laptop.
(E.g. for Python v3.8x (64-bit), GDAL package should be GDAL-3.3.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl)

Go to the folder where the binaries are downloaded in the command prompt window. (C:\Users\abc\GeoPandas dependencies)
Order of execution of the following commands matter.

```
pip install .\GDAL-3.3.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl

pip install .\pyproj-3.2.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl

pip install .\Fiona-1.8.20-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl

pip install .\Shapely-1.7.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl

pip install .\geopandas-0.9.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

[Credit](https://towardsdatascience.com/geopandas-installation-the-easy-way-for-windows-31a666b3610f)

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by @marianoju, the problem is likely because you do not have IPython installed in your current environment.

The simple solution is to install IPython in your current environment.

`conda install ipython`

An even better solution (in my opinion) is to install Jupyter notebook, Jupyter lab in your new conda environment.

`conda install jupyter`

`conda install jupyterlab`

This will install jupyter(lab) along with its all dependencies (and that includes IPython). So, any other lurking dependency issues would have been solved in one command.