# Choropleth map showing white page instead of the map

Tags: python, plotly, geojson, choropleth

I am working on a choropleth map and it is showing a white page instead of the map as shown here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/boYKY.png

I have both the geojson and the excel file downloaded in the same folder.

geojson https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N-rp9yHqE1Rzn2VxoAAweJ8-5XIjk61j/view?usp=sharing
excel https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NKeUg20XxJe0jccMgjj9pMxrTIIWeuQk/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100050178655652050254&rtpof=true&sd=true

Here is my code

```
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_excel('kraje.xlsx', sheet_name='List1')

regions_json = json.load(open("KRAJE.geojson", "r"))

fig = px.choropleth(df,
             locations="K_KRAJ",
             geojson=regions_json,
             color='OB1506')
fig.show()
```

The console of my browser in which I am viewing the map shows
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9awi.png)

I am using a jupyter notebook in the brave browser.

Can anyone please help me solve this? Thanks

**EDIT:**

I found the correct geojson file but now I have a different issue. Only one region is colored and not even in the correct color and the rest of the map even outside of my regions is colored in the same color. When I hover over my regions I can see that they are in the correct place but with a wrong color. And I also have no idea why the code colored the whole map and not only the regions from the geojson file. [here is an image of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rJgG.png)

new (should be correct) geojson https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S03NX5Q0pqgAsbJnjqt8O5w8gUHH1rt_/view?usp=sharing

```
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_excel('kraje.xlsx', sheet_name='List1')

regions_json = json.load(open("KRAJE.geojson", "r"))
for feature in regions_json['features']:
    feature["id"] = feature["properties"]["K_KRAJ"]

fig = px.choropleth(df,
             locations="K_KRAJ",
             geojson=regions_json,
             color='OB1506')
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)
fig.show()
```

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to Rob Raymond it finally works. There was an issue with the geojson file. I also had a ton of problems installing geopandas and the only tutorial that actually worked was installing each package separately (https://stackoverflow.com/a/69210111/17646343)

Comment: Please include your data in csv format and where you got the geojson from in your post. Makes it easier to debug.

Comment: I added links to the files for debugging. thanks

Comment: I think the reason is that the coordinate data in the geojson file provided is not latitude and longitude information. If you have latitude and longitude information, please try it.

Comment: I found the correct geojson but now I have a different issue. I edited my question with the new problem. Does anyone know why does it do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- there are multiple issues with your geojson

  1. need to define the CRS,  it's clearly not epsg:4326.  Appears to be UTM CRS for Czech Republic
  2. even with this there are invalid polygons
- with valid geojson, a few points you have missed

  - **locations** needs to be common across your data frame and geojson
  - **featureidkey** needs to be used to define you are joining on name

```
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import geopandas as gpd

files = {
    f.suffix: f
    for p in ["KRAJE*.*", "KRAJE*.*".lower()]
    for f in Path.home().joinpath("Downloads").glob(p)
}
# df = pd.read_excel('kraje.xlsx', sheet_name='List1')
df = pd.read_excel(files[".xlsx"], sheet_name="List1")

# regions_json = json.load(open("KRAJE.geojson", "r"))
regions_json = json.load(open(files[".geojson"], "r"))
regions_json = (
    gpd.read_file(files[".geojson"])
    .dropna()
    .set_crs("EPSG:32633", allow_override=True)
    .to_crs("epsg:4326")
    .__geo_interface__
)

fig = px.choropleth(
    df,
    locations="N_KRAJ",
    featureidkey="properties.name",
    geojson=regions_json,
    color="OB1506",
)
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=True)
fig
```

#### updated

- there are still issues with your *geojson*. Have fixed it using **geopandas** and `buffer(0)` (see [Fix invalid polygon in Shapely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833344/fix-invalid-polygon-in-shapely))
- with this and change to **plotly** parameters I can now generate a figure

```
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import geopandas as gpd
from pathlib import Path

files = {
    f.suffix: f
    for p in ["KRAJ_*.*", "KRAJE*.*".lower()]
    for f in Path.home().joinpath("Downloads").glob(p)
}
# df = pd.read_excel('kraje.xlsx', sheet_name='List1')
df = pd.read_excel(files[".xlsx"], sheet_name="List1")

# regions_json = json.load(open("KRAJE.geojson", "r"))
regions_json = json.load(open(files[".json"], "r"))
# geometry is still invalid!!! force it to valid by buffer(0)
regions_json = gpd.read_file(files[".json"]).assign(geometry=lambda d: d["geometry"].buffer(0)).__geo_interface__

fig = px.choropleth(
    df,
    locations="K_KRAJ",
    featureidkey="properties.K_KRAJ",
    geojson=regions_json,
    color="OB1506",
)
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=True)
fig
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I found the correct geojson but now I have a different issue. I edited my question with the new problem. Does anyone know why does it do this?

Comment: updated - your geometry still has validation issues that need to be worked around

Comment: thanks. I am now stuck on installing geopandas because it takes too long and there are so many conflicts. About the geojson...I got it from mapshaper.org after inserting shape files and then transforming the coordinates to wgs84 format. So its weird that there was another issue :(

Comment: I'll take a look at getting geojson to work correctly from source

Comment: I can't find Czech regions as geojson.  Found as Shapefile, but the way I would convert that to GeoJson is using geopandas...

Comment: Oh yes thanks Rob it finally works. After a whole day of trying to install geopandas :D.